# Check total post data size on submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to show alert if the total post data size on submit is greater than 1mb. Here is my code. Please give me a solution of this.

```
function myfunction() {
    var ttlSize = 0;

    $('#validate_me').find('[type="file"]').each(function() {
        ttlSize += this.files[0].size;
    });

    if (ttlSize > 1 * 1048576) { // 1MB
        alert("size will exceed post max size"); // this will exceed post_max_size PHP setting, now handle...
    } else if ($("#validate_me").not("[type='file']").serialize().length) {
        alert("size will exceed max_file_uploads size"); // this will exceed max_file_uploads PHP setting, now handle...
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: why  1 * 1048576 ?

Comment: i check that if size is greater than i mb

Comment: why not ttlSize > 1048576?

Comment: i also do this but its not working i really need the solution how we can check post data size and show alert before submission if you can please help me

Comment: Which browser and version are you trying this on?